# How can I pass a PDF to Adobe Reader on Android by intent to edit ist directly and not a copy?

Tags: android, pdf, adobe, edit

I use the following code to open a pdf form. If I use Acrobat Reader it's not possible to write back to the original file. It always makes a copy which I only could guess but newer know for shure in my app.

I know that it has to be possible to edit the original because if I open a pdf from any file manager (e.g. the one from Asus) Adobe Reader edits it directly.

Xodo PDF allows direct edit. It even supports the correct ACTION_EDIT intent but I'm afraid that our users insist to use Adobe...

How can I edit the original with Adobe?

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator + "x.pdf");
if(file.exists())
{
    file.setWritable(true,false);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()),
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file);
    intent.setDataAndType(contentUri,"application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find the solution? I'm facing the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Xodo PDF seems to be the only solution. Our customer accepted it.With Excel it seems to be the same crap - there we use Google Sheets now...

Comment: Looks like the latest Android updates completely destroyed the ACTION_EDIT intent. I can't save back to the provided file anymore. No matter what app is used to edit. Crap.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment even Xodo doesn't work anymore but I was lucky to realized that OneDrive-PDF-Viewer does.